# how to send text to textbox through a different class?

Tags: c#, textbox

I'm working in a Windows Form Application project with c#. There is a graphical main form called MainForm with a textbox that works like a log viewer. Also, there are a lot of classes that must send information about their work through the textbox.

I already have this code in Program.cs. It create a public member

```
  public static MainForm mainForm;

  public static Main()
  {
    ...
    mainForm = new MainForm();
    Application.Run(mainForm);

    // Application.Run(new MainForm());  I commented this default line
  }
```

Inside of MainForm.cs I have this:

```
public void sendMessage(string message)
{
// puts message in textbox...
}
```

Finally, I can access from another class by this way:

```
class otherClass
{
  ...

  private void someFunction(){
    ...


    Program.mainForm.sendMessage("send to log!");

  }
}
```

How can I change this behaivor?
Does it exists another way more efficient?

Comment: why do you use send message function? wouldn't it be better that you call it mainForm = new MainForm(); mainForm.textbox1.text="sometext";

Comment: good idea, it works, but I  use sendMessage() to add the message to a log file too

Comment: how about having sendMessage() function in your main form?

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of better ways to do what you are trying to do.  It depends on the structure of your application.

You probably want to create a class to do the logging.  In this class you would create an event that is fired when the log is changed/added to.  Then any module in your app can call this logging class, any any UI elements you want to monitor the logging can just subscribe to the events like so:

```
public static class MyLogger
{
    private static List<string> log = new List<string>();

    public static event EventHandler LogAdded;

    public static void Log(string message)
    {
        log.Add(message);

        if (LogAdded != null)
            LogAdded(null, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public static string GetLastLog()
    {
        if (log.Count > 0)
            return log[log.Count - 1];
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

You then have the ability to add to the log from anywhere with this line:

```
MyLogger.Log("message");
```

Any your form can subscribe to all log events like so:

```
MyLogger.LogAdded += new EventHandler(MyLogger_LogAdded);
```

Just remember to remove the event like follows when your form is closed/disposed:

```
MyLogger.LogAdded -= new EventHandler(MyLogger_LogAdded);
```

And you would respond to the event like so:

```
void MyLogger_LogAdded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox.Text = textBox.Text + Environment.NewLine + MyLogger.GetLastLog();
}
```

Instead of logging strings, you can easily make your own class to represent a log entry that contains any data you wish to store/organize/display.

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea:
Why don't you implement TraceListener that is going to write into your text box and use Trace.Write everywhere in your app.

```
class MyTraceListener : TraceListener
{
TextBox textBox;
public MyTraceListener(TextBox textBox)
{
this.textBox = textBox;
}

public override void Write(string value)
{
this.textBox.AppendText(value);
}

}
```

In your MainForm ctor,

```
public MainForm()
{
var tl - new MyTraceListener(this.textBox);
Trace.Listeners.Add(tl);
}
```

By overriding other methods, you can customize your output.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an event in `otherClass` and register it in your `MainForm`.

Here is a simple example for events: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/simplesteventexample.aspx