# send generated value from class to textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a library that generates strings to a function called MessageOut. This function, i cannot change the structure of.

It looks like this:

```
public void MessageOut(string msg) //params or return-type cannot be changed
{
    Console.WriteLine(msg);       
}
```

I have a textbox in my form that i want to show this message in.

How would I go about appending `msg` to that textbox?

I've tried:

```
public void MessageOut(string msg) //params or return-type cannot be changed
{
    Console.WriteLine(msg);
    sendMessageTextBox(msg);       
}

public string[] sendMessageTextBox(params string[] msg)
{ 
     string send = "";
     foreach(var i in msg){send = i;}
     return send;
}
```

Form:

```
private void getWaveformBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     MyClass className = new MyClass();
     foreach(var i in className.sendMessageTextBox())
     {
          errorTextBox.Text += i;
     }
}
```

For obvious reasons, this doesn't work ,but i'm unsure how to go about doing this. (i've tried: [how to send text to textbox through a different class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8622937/how-to-send-text-to-textbox-through-a-different-class)

[Sending information to a textbox from a class to a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13296891/sending-information-to-a-textbox-from-a-class-to-a-form))

However, i cannot seem to get those solutions to work.

Any help is much appreciated.

TL;DR - i basically want to show the new strings that `messageOut` recieves in a textbox

Comment: You are overriding previous value in `foreach` loop (`foreach(var i in msg){send = i;}`). You may use `send += i;`

Comment: @HusseinGolshani still the same thing

Comment: And in `foreach(var i in className.sendMessageTextBox())` you are enumerating `char`! Let us to know what is sample data and what is your desired result in TextBox .

Comment: There's no `send text to textbox` or `send through a different class`. Forms are just objects. Objects call methods on other objects or read/write properties. You don't have multiple forms here though. If you want to keep track of string messages add them to a List<string> or Queue<string> before calling `MessageOut`. If you want to convert them to a string for display, `var fullString-String.Join("\n",thatList);`. Set the Textbox.Text property to that

Comment: Are you going to *write* to that textbox? If not, why not use a ListBox and bind it to the List,Queue, whatever contains the strings?

Comment: I agree with what Panagiotis said, forms are just a class. What I would like to clarify is who instantiates the class with `MessageOut`, it you do just pass the `TextBox` / a queue / list whatever in the constructor. If you don't and this class instantiated via IoC / framework please say that in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in may different ways, one of them will be to use a queue, fill it from `MessageOut` and drain it on button press.

```
public class MessageHandler /* , MessageOutInterface */
{
    private readonly Queue<string> messages;

    public MessageHandler()
    {
        this.messages = new Queue<string>();
    }

    public void MessageOut(string message)
    {
        this.messages.Enqueue(message);
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> PendingMessages() 
    {
        string message;
        while (this.messages.Count > 0)
            yield return this.messages.Dequeue();
    }
}
```

Your UI code

```
private void getWaveformBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     foreach(var i in messageHandler.PendingMessages())
     {
          errorTextBox.Text += i;
     }
}
```

If `MessageOut` is called on one thread (i.e. not the main thread) and the button press obviously happens on the main thread you'll need a thread safe approach:

```
public class MessageHandler /* , MessageOutInterface */
{
    private readonly object syncRoot = new Object();
    private readonly Queue<string> messages;

    public MessageHandler()
    {
        this.messages = new Queue<string>();
    }

    public void MessageOut(string message)
    {
        lock (this.syncRoot)
        {
            this.messages.Enqueue(message);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> PendingMessages() 
    {
        lock (this.syncRoot)
        {
            var pending = this.messages.ToArray();
            this.messages.Clear();
            return pending;
        }
    }
}
```

This is not the best way to synchronize the threads but you can ask another question about synchronization.

Comment: this crashes, "queue is empty all the time :/ "

Comment: This is a very complicated way to do `String.Join("\n",anythingEnumerable)`. And generates a *lot* of temporary strings too

Comment: @Matan Thanks for your contribution, however, the function "MessageOut" must be in another class. I cannot duplicate it like this or move it into another class.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Is OP wants to get the messages only on button press you have to save the strings somewhere, you can either do that with a queue, a `StringBuilder` or anything else that can be copied and cleared. Unless I missed what the OP wanted to do.

Comment: @MatanShahar i managed to modify your answer to get it to work, thanks! I will mark it as an answer as it brought me to the solution.

Comment: @MatanShahar that anything can be used with `String.Join()`: `errorTextBox.Text=String.Join("\n",anything);`. None of this code is needed, not even the locks - that anything could be a `ConcurrentQueue<string>`